# Find the dimension of the subspace of R^4 spanned by the set {(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(1,2,0,1),(0,0,0,1)}. Hence find a basis for the subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, dimension-theory-algebra

GIven set is not Linearly dependent hence not a basis. So should we take basis as {(1.0.0.0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)} and give as dim(R^4) = 4 or any other solution is expected?

Comment: You’re supposed to find a basis for a **subspace** of $\mathbb R^4$. Is $(0,0,1,0)$ even in the span of the given set of vectors? Observe that the third component of every one of them is $0$.

Comment: thanks. i am new to this topic. Hence, i was confused about basis and dimensions. But now i am clear

Answer (score 1):

If you row reduce the matrix formed by these vectors (as lines), you'll be able to compute its rank (it is 3). This is the maximum number of linearly independent rows. So, you can just pick 3 linearly independent vectors from  the subspace as its basis, for instance  $(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0),(0,0,0,1)$.

Comment: To be specific can we choose those columns of the original matrix A which correspond to the pivot positions in RREF.